# Can't dump meminfo error: Android 4.2.1

Tags: android, database, dump

I got a strange error with my ACRA error reporting system which I cannot figure out what is causing this. I searched on the internet and there is very little to find out about this issue at first sight. The errors goes as follows :

```
java.lang.Error: Error copying database
```

//...

```
Permission Denial: can't dump meminfo from from pid=xx, uid=xx without permission android.permission.DUMP
```

My question is if this is fixable with coding or is this due to the version of the android system or something? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See this discussion:
https://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=100

Shortly - from android 4.0 third party applications can't dump any system process information, for example meminfo.